# PHP entering time into a database

Tags: php, time, mysqli

I am having an issue updating an database entries with a certain time.

```
$currentTime = time("H:i:s", strtotime("16:00:00"));

mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE Table SET time='" . $currentTime . "' WHERE id = 1);
```

but the time in the database is displaying as 00:00:00

the datatype in my database is set to TIME...should it be DATE?

What Am I am doing wrong?

Comment: `time` returns the current unix timestamp as an integer. Perhaps you intended to use `date`?

Comment: You also have a typo with your quotes in the mysqli_query.

Comment: [`time() — Return current Unix timestamp`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)

Comment: Why aren't you just inserting `"16:00:00"` in the database? Is this your actual code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `time` by `date`

The function `time` only return the unixtimestamp ... you need to format the unix timestamp as H:i:s.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use MySql date/time [functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)?

See [CURRENTTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-time) and then use

```
mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE Table SET time=CURRENTTIME() WHERE id = 1");
```

Comment: Note that the time zone of the database server will be used, not the server where the script runs.

Comment: @Jack - just store as GMT/UTC and use CONVERT_TZ() function.

Comment: I know, but I'm not the one asking the question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`echo time("H:i:s", strtotime("16:00:00"));`

produces

`1370830176`

This is not the time format expected by MySQL.

Your query becomes:

`UPDATE Table SET time='1370830176' WHERE id = 1`

It should be simply:

`UPDATE Table SET time='16:00:00' WHERE id = 1`

So, you don't need this:

`$currentTime = time("H:i:s", strtotime("16:00:00"));`

You only need:

`$currentTime = "16:00:00";`